# Bayes rule with 2 conditions on each side of the bar and repeated events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The binary variables $A,B,C \in \{0,1\}$ are not independent. I need to solve for the probability of $A$ and $B$ occurring simultaneously given that $C$ and $A$ occur: $P[A=1, B=1| C=1, A=1]$.

I have expanded the probability using the Bayes theorem, but I'm not sure it's correct.
$$
Lemma1: P[a=1, b=1|b=1] = P[a=1, b=1]\\
Lemma2: P[a=1,b=1|c=1] = P[d|c=1], d=\{a=1,b=1\}\\
Lemma3: P[d|c=1,a=1] = \frac{P[c=1|d,a=1]*P[d|a=1]}{P[c=1|a=1]}\\\
\\
P[A=1, B=1| C=1, A=1] = P[\alpha|C=1, A=1]; \alpha=\{A=1, B=1\}\\
P[\alpha|C=1, A=1] = \frac{P[C=1|\alpha,A=1]*P[\alpha|A=1]}{P[C=1|A=1]}\\
= \frac{P[C=1|A=1, B=1,B=1]*P[A=1, B=1|A=1]}{P[C=1|A=1]}\\
= \frac{P[C=1|A=1, B=1]*P[A=1, B=1]}{P[C=1|A=1]}
$$
That's as far as I've come. Are my lemmas and process correct? Is there a way to further simplify the probability? If possible, I'd like to express the probability in terms of the quantities I have information for: $P[A=1], P[C=1], P[A=1|C=1], P[B=1,C=1]$

Note: Lemma 3 came from [Bayes rule for two conditioned events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463896/bayes-rule-for-two-conditioned-events)

Comment: I would start with $P[A=1, B=1\mid  C=1, A=1]=P[B=1\mid  C=1, A=1] = \frac{P[B=1,  C=1, A=1]}{P[C=1, A=1]}$ and then stop if I have no more information.

Comment: Lemma 1 should read $P[a=1, b=1\mid b=1]=P[a=1\mid b=1]$ .